# random (read only) access to elements of Eigen::SparseVector

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Consider the following silly code piece

```
typedef Eigen::SparseVector<std::complex<double>, Eigen::ColMajor,long long> Vector;

Vector V = CreateData();

for(i=0;i<V.size(),++i)
{
  DoSomething( Vector.coeffRef(i));
}
```

I'm kind of interesting (for some purpose) to access (say) every elements of sparse vector `V` and expect, of course, zero to be returned when accessing non initialized entries.

What I'm surprisingly found is that at the access to a non existing\initialized entry, this entry is **being created on reading**, with the correct value of zero of course, but why???

I'm definitely not interesting in such behavior. All I want to get is zero returned whenever a non initialized entry being accessed for reading, otherwise a cast to full matrix is faster.
Is there an alternative to `.coeffRef` that won't allocate new entries.

Comment: Accessing every element of a sparse vector will be slower than accessing every element of a dense vector. To actually benefit from the sparse-ness you should only iterate through the non-zero elements. (I don't know, what `DoSomething(0)` is supposed to do, and if it has to happen in order). For the actual question, see the answer of @ggael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `coeff()` method instead of the `coeffRef()` one. It does exactly what you want. On the other hand, `coeffRef()` returns a reference for read-write access, so the element must exist.